# Crystal Reports XI - Trying to move the contents the vertical side of the page to the horizontal side

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I am trying to create a report using Crystal Reports XI that is able to look similar to an Excel spreadsheet. One of the requirements is that it needs to be a landscape page and they want a header that shows the ItemID's in the header.

All the headers that I need to show is as follows (In the order from left to right)
- Invoice Number
- Account Name
- Item ID (Dynamic, currently a list of at most 30 items)

The data showing under the header is needing to be able to show a quantity per Item ID, the actual account name, the invoice number that the items were found on.
 [Example of the desired appearance of report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zcqa7.png)

In my report so far, I have managed to create the Dynamic ItemID header using a subreport, the details section in the subreport and the format as multiple columns option on the details section. Now I am having issues with trying to make it so that I can put the other information needed into the report without having to make the report look for statically defined item ids.

Is there any way to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: [Additional image of what I am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/as9Ra.png)
EDIT 2:[A picture of the cross tab attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3krca.png)

Comment: can you show example how data structure looks like

Comment: Hi Siva, I am not sure exactly what you mean. I am using an SQL query to generate the data that is needed. The field types are Invoice Number(Number), ItemID(String(75)), Quantity(Number), Account Name (String(150))

Comment: Actually I am unable to understand where you are struck...

Comment: You know in excel how we have the columns and rows? If I envision one of our companies reports as an Excel document it would be that the headers are just labels and all of the relevant information would be in the rows. So if I built the report the way it has been done in the past, the Item ID's would be showing up in the rows with the invoice number followed by the quantity of that specific item. What I have been asked to do, is make the specific itemid's become the header labels and then show a number under each of the header labels corresponding to the quantity sold on an invoice.

Comment: ok got it.. will post my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create formulas for each and every item in ItemID column.

So your formulas would be:

Create a text field with name `Monitor` and rest of columns and place them one by one like you placed in image.

Now to get the data write formulas like below:

```
if ItemID="monitor"
then Quantity
```

Place this formula in detail to get data for monitor and in the same way create formulas for all items in the column.

Let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Thanks Siva, I was hoping to not need to set the ItemID Statically for the purpose of the formulas, as it causes myself or others in the future to need to edit the report anytime a new item gets added. Is there a way to have it use the dynamic itemid headers to define when it shows the quantity for that item?

Comment: Yes there is a way, But in that case it will be difficult to accomodate invoice and account number. If you need only Item ID then use cross tabs

Comment: Place the ItemID field in cross tab then you will get the design you neede

Comment: So that looks mostly like what I am wanting, and I have added a second cross tab that only has invoice numbers as rows. Now is there a way for me to remove the totals column/row from the crosstab but still show the invoice number?

Comment: can you show how cross tab you created looks like and what you want to remove

Comment: Just added a photo link to the original post showing what my crystal shows. All the invoice numbers line up properly, but I dont need the Total column or Total row to be displaying on the crosstab containing the invoice number (The left block of information)

Comment: ok.. go to cross tab expert and there go to 3rd tab (I guess currently don't have CR) there you will be able to see few options on totals, Play a bit with those you should be able to remove.

Comment: Awesome - that looks a lot better now. Thanks Siva. My (hopefully) last question about this then is how would I change the headers to allow for larger strings to fit in them? Currently, my longest possible string is 150 characters but I am only seeing parts of the names (ID's and Account Names) before they get cut off making it so that I cant fully read the information presented

Comment: increase the length to some extent and then right click on the header click on format and then check `Can Grow` and write value `0`

Comment: Don't forget to accept it as answered so that thread is closed and others can use